# Using Date.parse() in javascript, shows NaN while using Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firebug

I get NAN while debugging in firebug for Date.parse(). Could you help me on this? Is there an alternative for Date.parse()?

Comment: Why don't you show the code that is giving you NaN? What is the value you are giving to Date.parse()? Also Java !== JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.parse` will return `NaN` if you give it a string that it can't parse as a date.

There is only [one format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) that `Date.parse` is *required* to support, which is a [not-quite-ISO-8601 format](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2014/07/javascripts-datetime-format-is-not-iso.html). However, every JavaScript engine I've ever seen also supports "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss" (American order, even in non-American locales) provided you use `/` not `-`.

There are various libraries you can use to get more parsing options, if you prefer doing that to reformatting your string. The flavor-of-the-week is [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), but of course that may not be appropriate to your needs and there are other options.